# Getting rid of form and use just button to create new record

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Rails 3.1. I have the following:

```
// _form.html.erb
<%= form_for ([@country, @state], :remote => true) do |td| %>
  <div id= "state_errors" style="display:none"></div>
  <%= td.text_field :position, :id => "next_state" %>
    <div class="actions">
        <%= td.submit %>
    </div>
<% end %>

// global.js
function nextState() {
    Array.max = function( array ) {
        return Math.max.apply( Math, array );
    };
    var getLastState = $("input.sortable_state_item_position").map(function() {
        return $(this).val();
    }).get();
    getLastState.push("0");

    return Array.max(getLastState) + 1;
}
$("input#next_state").val(nextState());

// states_controller.rb
class StatesController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :load

  def load
    @country = Country.find(params[:country_id])
    @states = State.all
  end

  def create
    @state = @country.states.build(params[:state])
    @state.save
  end

  ...
end
```

You will notice that I created a `form` tag for user to create a record when the submit button is clicked. But I am not sure if I could get rid of the entire `form_for` and just use a normal `a` or `button` to trigger the `create` because I kinda thing that the entire form is redundant as there is no need for the user to input anything. My javascript enters the value automatically.

Please advise. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my State controller:

```
def create
  @state = @country.states.build(params[:trip_day])
  @state.position = State.where(:country_id => @country.id).maximum(:position).to_i + 1
  @state.save
end
```

Replace the `form` with this:

```
<%= link_to "Add new state", country_states_path(@country), :remote => true, :method => :post %>
```

I removed the `nextState()` function, entire `form`.